# Why am I getting an 'Objects are not valid as a React child' in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am passing an array to a `FlatList` but I am getting an errror:

> 'Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found:
>   object with keys {id, customer, etc}).

I've tried putting brackets around item and removing them but nothing is working.  Does anyone know how to fix this error?

```
renderSearches = () => {
    if (this.state.products.length) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.suggestionContainer}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.products}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                    renderItem={({item}) => <SuggestionItem value={item} onSelect={this.updateSearchTerm} />}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }

    return (<View></View>);
}
```

here is the SuggestionItem render:

```
render() {
    const {value} = this.props;
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.suggestion} onPress={() => {this.props.onSelect(value)}}>
            <Text style={styles.suggestionText}>{value}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you also provide the render method of `SuggestionItem`.

Comment: I have added it now.

Comment: `value` is an object which you're passing to `Text` element. It should be string not an object.

Comment: It's because you're passing `item` as the `value` prop to `< SuggestionItem />` and you're trying to render it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your SuggestionItems render method should have -

```
<Text style={styles.suggestionText}>{value.customer}</Text>
```

or something like

```
<Text style={styles.suggestionText}>{value.name}</Text>
```

instead of directly rendering the whole object in a text component

```
<Text style={styles.suggestionText}>{value}</Text>
```

Comment: Thank you, akshay. Only this helped me. Then why can't I render whole object?

Answer (score 1):

Like the red box is telling you :) You are rendering a object with keys, in your case value is an object which looks like this =>

```
value: {
    id: "1234"
    customer: "0"
    ........
}
```

In other words your array which you are passing to your FlatList is an Array with Objects...So you have to choose which object property you want to display in your Text component

```
render() {
  const {id, customer, perm_override, order_count, cost_flag .....} = this.props.value;
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.suggestion} onPress={() => {this.props.onSelect(value)}}>
        <Text style={styles.suggestionText}>{customer}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`value` is an object which you're passing to `Text` element. It should be string not an object. For example:

```
<Text style={styles.suggestionText}>{value.cutomer}</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i had an array of object in my data collection  which i didn't know  until i added 'toString()' like this {room.data.name.toString()},after deleting the object in my data collection i then remove 'toString()' and the problem was solved